# Tabla no pinta los campos

Tags: angular, angular7

Tengo la siguiente tabla como ven no me pinta las filas con los datos del lado del servidor el api get funciona correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este el código html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr *ngFor="let pd of service.list">
    <td (click)="populateForm(pd)">{{pd.CardOwnerName}}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(pd)">{{pd.CardNumber}}</td>
    <td (click)="populateForm(pd)">{{pd.ExpirationDate}}</td>
    <td>
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger" (click)="onDelete(pd.PMId)"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Servicio que llama el api GET

```
 readonly rootURL = 'http://localhost:59035/api';
  list : PaymentDetail[];


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    
         refreshList(){
            this.http.get(this.rootURL + '/PaymentDetail/')
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => this.list = res as PaymentDetail[]);
          }
```

En el ts de este componente lo cargo de esta manera

```
      ngOnInit() {
        this.service.refreshList();
debugger;
    console.log(this.service.refreshList);
        
      }
```

modelos

```
export class PaymentDetail {

        PMId :number;
        CardOwnerName: string;
        CardNumber: string;
        ExpirationDate: string;
        CVV: string;
    }
```

Pruebo el api desde postman y me trae los datos correctamente

en el debugger me sale lo siguiente

**formData: {PMId: 0, CardOwnerName: "", CardNumber: "", ExpirationDate: "", CVV: ""}
http: HttpClient {handler: HttpInterceptingHandler}
rootURL: "http://localhost:59035/api"
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta lo siguiente

Servicio:

```
refreshList(){
   return this.http.get(this.rootURL + '/PaymentDetail/');
}
```

ts: (aqui asumo que lo que responde el servicio es la lista, nada mas)

```
public lista = [];
public isLoading = true;

ngOnInit() {
   this.isLoading = true;
   this.service.refreshList()
     .pipe(finalize( () => this.isLoading = false))
     .subscribe(
        (response) => 
        {
           console.log('response:', response);
           this.lista = response
        }
     )   
}
```

html

```
<table class="table table-striped" *ngIf=(!isLoading)>
   <tr *ngFor="let pd of lista">
      ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

Si funciona pues perfecto, sino... me podrías mostrar que imprime en consola el console.log :) gracias

Answer (score 0):

No estas obteniendo el resultado después de que lo cargaste.

```
refreshList(){
            this.http.get(this.rootURL + '/PaymentDetail/')
            .toPromise()
             //Hasta aqui todo se ve bien, pero this.list no lo vuelves a usar. 
            .then(res => this.list = res as PaymentDetail[]);
          }
```

```
   ngOnInit() {
        this.service.refreshList();
        //De la manera que lo implementas no te va a dar tiempo de que
        // se muestren los datos. Es una operación asincrona. 
        console.log(this.service.list);
        
      }
```

Para que tu codigo funcione debes resolver la promesa en tu componente, no en el servicio.

```
//Modifica esta operación para que retorne la promesa sin resolverla:

refreshList(){
            return this.http.get(this.rootURL + '/PaymentDetail/')
            .toPromise()
            
          }
```

Despues en tu `component.ts` obtienes los datos asi:

```
//Ahora esta variable tiene que ir aqui, en el componente
list:PaymentDetail[]=[]

ngOnInit() {
        this.service
           .refreshList()
           .then(res => {

            this.list = res as PaymentDetail[]
}));
      }
```

Y en el html sustituye : `<tr *ngFor="let pd of service.list">` por `<tr *ngFor="let pd of list">`

Comment: Pongo todo lo que me dices y se desaparece la tabla es decir que no muestra ya nada, pero miro por consola y esta el array con los datos

Comment: Actualize mi respuesta. Revisa si te funciona.

Comment: Super raro sigue sin mostrar nada he intentado de mil formas y no se que será

Comment: Pon {{list | json }} antes del *ngFor, no dentro de una etiqueta. Y pon una captura del código y lo que te da el navegador como resultado.

Comment: `[TU RESPUESTA]` Pon {{list | json }} antes del *ngFor, no dentro de una etiqueta. Y pon una captura del código y lo que te da el navegador como resultado.

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo Posiblemente tu api vs tu clase no coincidan.